# VBA dictionary not adding values

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I'm trying to write a function that searches a certain column (Call it Column A) for the term "Request". Once this row is found it searches another column (Call it Column B) in the same row for a unique term. The goal is to count how many unique terms in Column B correspond to the term "Request" in column A. The way I've tried to do this is by creating a dictionary and adding a term to it if that term does not already exist in the dictionary. The program counts how many terms are added to the dictionary so I know how many unique terms there are. However, the code I have now just keeps adding every term to the dictionary, regardless of whether or not the term already exists or not. I've been trying to figure it out for a while now and can't quite figure it out. Here's the code:

```
   j = 0
   For i = 1 To LastRow
        If Cells(i, 13).Value Like "Request" Then
            Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            If Not dic.exists(Cells(i, 13)) Then
                ucount = ucount + 1
                dic.Add j, Cells(i, 13)
                j = j + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
```

I think the issue might lie with the dic.Add feature, but I'm not sure. I'm relatively new to VBA and coding in general.

Comment: `Add` parameters are `key`, `value` - the `Exists` method checks the key, not the value, and you're adding `j` as the key when you add an item.  Also you have no wildcards in your `Like` comparison, so it will only find the exact value "Request" - maybe you meant "*Request*" ?

Comment: Good suggestion, but I actually had it the other way around before and it didn't work like that either. I mixed it around to see what would happen but obviously it didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dim dict as Object, tmp
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For i = 1 To LastRow
    If Cells(i, "A").Value = "Request" Then
        tmp = Cells(i, "B").Value
        If Not dict.exists(tmp) Then
            dict.Add tmp, 1
        End If
    End If
Next i 

Debug.Print dict.Count 'no need for a separate counter
```

Comment: +1 no need for separate counter variable. Also, unless the user needs to modify the stored *value* if the key already exists, it's safe to omit the `If Not dict.exists` test in favor of simply `dict(tmp) = 1`

Comment: Sorry I'm fairly new to this site and didn't think to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is where this line is:

```
        Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

Each time you hit this line, your dictionary is reset and reinitialized.

Move it before your entire loop:

```
   j = 0
   Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   For i = 1 To LastRow
        If Cells(i, 13).Value Like "Request" Then
            If Not dic.exists(Cells(i, 13).value) Then
                ucount = ucount + 1
                dic.Add j, Cells(i, 13).value
                j = j + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: I just tried it and unfortunately I still have the same issue. The code just keeps looping through the second if statement regardless of whether or not the term has been seen or not.

Comment: you `if not dic.exist` must be the key value , being J !,